# How to insert into database SQL transaction?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net, sqlcommand

I've got a `Log` method:

```
public void Log(string log)
{
   command = new SqlCommand() { Connection = connection };
   command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Logs (Date, Login, Transact) " +
      $"VALUES ('{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")}', '{Login}', '{log}')";
   connection.Open();
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   connection.Close();
}
```

In the log string I have a value like this:

```
"INSERT '/*something*/'"
```

or

```
"UPDATE: '/*smth*/' => '/*smth*/'"
```

But it's not working - I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax

How can I do it?

Comment: Don't concatenate your values directly in your sql string : the single quote of your ```log``` value is messing up the query. You should use ```SqlParameter``` instead to assign your parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Logs (Date, Login, Transact) " +
   $"VALUES (@date, @login, @transact)";
command.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
command.Parameters.Add("@login", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = Login;
command.Parameters.Add("@transact", SqlDbType.Text).Value = log;
```

Comment: `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")` should just be `DateTime.Now` since it's a stongly-typed `DateTime` parameter.